# Sum of the area of infinite similar equilateral triangles

Tags: trigonometry, triangles, trigonometric-series, geometric-series

[image: Infinite triangles inside a triangle with a 28 degree angle]

How would I solve for the side depicted in the picture?

Comment: how much are you willing to pay? ;-) by "pay" i mean express some of your own ideas about the problem. questions posed without any background info on what you know that might be relevant are not generally very highly regarded on MSE

Comment: I know that this problem somehow relates to the sum of an infinite geometric series, and that's about all I've got. I don't know how the 28 degrees relates to the scaling down of each successive triangle, but I'd like some input.

Comment: OK, good! suppose the scaling down factor is $a$ for linear dimensions. what is it for areas? using that, let the area of the largest triangle be $A$. now as a first step can you write down $277 = f(A,a)$? where i'll leave you to find the form of the (fairly simple) function $f$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Call $S_n$ the side of the $n^{th}$ equilateral triangle from the right side. The area is

$$A = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \dfrac{\sqrt{3}}{4}S_n^2 = 277$$

If you can get $S_n$ in terms of $S_1$ for all $n$, and evaluate the series, then you can find $S_1$ as desired.

If you look at the upper triangle in between the two right-most equilateral triangles, you can see (using standard techniques) that the angles are $88^o, 60^o, 32^o$. Using the law of sines, you find that

$$\dfrac{S_2}{\sin(32^o)} = \dfrac{S_1}{\sin(88^o)} \iff S_2 = \dfrac{\sin(32^o)}{\sin(88^o)}S_1$$

and similarly that

$$S_n=\left(\dfrac{\sin(32^o)}{\sin(88^o)}\right)^{n-1}S_1$$

From here, after making the substitution in the above series, you will get a geometric series in which $S_1^2$ may be factored out.

Answer (score 0):

Assume that
- angle of incline is $\alpha$
- width of first* triangle is $2a_1$
- width of second* triangle is $2a_2$
etc.
**counting from the right, and using this convention throughout*

Consider the apex of the first two triangles.
Their respective heights are $a_1\sqrt3$ and $a_2\sqrt3$.
Their horizontal separation is $a_1+a_2$.
Their vertical separation (difference in height) is $(a_1-a_2)\sqrt3$.

Hence we have
$$\tan\alpha=\frac{(a_1-a_2)\sqrt3}{a_1+a_2}\\
r=\frac{a_1}{a_2}=\frac{\sqrt3-\tan\alpha}{\sqrt3+\tan\alpha}=\frac{a_i}{a_{i+1}}\\
\Rightarrow a_i=a_1r^{i-1}$$
i.e. heights of triangles are in GP.

Also, we are given that the total the area of all triangles is 277, i.e.
$$\begin{align}
277&=\sum_{i=1}^\infty A_i
=\sum_{i=1}^\infty\sqrt3a_i^2\\
&=a_1^2\sqrt3\sum_{i=1}^\infty r^{2(i-1)}\\
&=\frac{a_1^2\sqrt3}{1-r^2}\\
a_1^2&=\frac{277}{\sqrt3}(1-r^2)
\end{align}$$

Putting $\alpha=28^\circ$ gives $r=0.684079, a_1=9.22422$.
Hence side of first triangle is $2a_1=\color{red}{18.4485}$.

---

NB - it would have been a "neat" problem if, e.g. $\alpha$ had been set to $30^\circ$ (or $\frac\pi6$ radians), and the total area to, say, $4\sqrt 3$, as that would result in $r=\frac 12$ and $a_1=3$.